# Change properties of TextView in ListView row xml

Tags: java, android, listview, textview

Hey, I want to change the TypeFace of one of the TextViews to an external font.. How can I do that?
Code:

```
public class English extends Activity {
<...>
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.quran_english);

    listview=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.QuranEnglishListView);    
    <..add into list..>
    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
            this,
            list,
            R.layout.quran_english_row,
            new String[] {"Arabic","English"},
            new int[] {R.id.QuranEnglishTextViewArabic,R.id.QuranEnglishTextViewEnglish});

    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

xml for each row (quran_english_row.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout android:gravity="right" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        <TextView android:textSize="21px" android:text="TextView" android:id="@+id/QuranEnglishTextViewArabic" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView android:textSize="21px" android:text="TextView" android:id="@+id/QuranEnglishTextViewEnglish" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

xml for the layout (quran_english.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical">
    <ListView android:id="@+id/QuranEnglishListView" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"></ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

This crashes because of NullPointer:

```
  ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.QuranEnglishTextViewArabic)).setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"dejavusans.ttf"));
```

So how can I reach the TextView that is in the row to change its TypeFace? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to get the layout for each list item by

> View rowView = adapter.getView(...);

Then get the TextView of the layout by

> TextView txt = (TextView)rowView .findViewById(R.id.QuranEnglishTextViewEnglish);
>   txt.setTypeFace(...);

and set your TypeFaces. Haven't tested that yet, but i guess it could work.

But I recommend extending your own BaseAdapter. Then create another list-row class which provides the inflated layouts for your BaseAdapter. There you'll be able to set the typefaces easily for every TextView.

Answer (score 0):

try this links it works          http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2011/04/using-custom-fonts-on-android.html       see steps and class MyTextView and MyButton shown above layout